# program to get a unique list (List) of every 5th and every 7th object from an array

Tags: java

this is my sample code

```
Object[] a=new Object[n];
for(int i=4;i<a.length;i+=5)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}       
for(int i=6;i<a.length;i+=7)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: i am getting 5th and 7th elements but how can i get uniquely like {5th elemt,7th element,10th elemet,14th ele.......}

Comment: Are you asking how not to include 35th element twice?

Comment: ya,not include 35 two times only uniquely elements should be displayed.means 35 should be display only once

Comment: @Jayakrishna i posted an answer, have a look

Comment: Store elements in **java.util.Set** to get unique element list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Modulus operator %`. No need to loop twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        //Object[] a = new Object[20];
        Object[] a = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
                32, 33, 34, 35 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 4 && i % 7 == 6) {
                System.out.println("Multiple of 5 and 7 both - " + a[i]);
            } else if (i % 5 == 4) {
                System.out.println("Multiple of 5 - " + a[i]);
            } else if (i % 7 == 6) {
                System.out.println("Multiple of 7 - " + a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Multiple of 5 - 5
Multiple of 7 - 7
Multiple of 5 - 10
Multiple of 7 - 14
Multiple of 5 - 15
Multiple of 5 - 20
Multiple of 7 - 21
Multiple of 5 - 25
Multiple of 7 - 28
Multiple of 5 - 30
Multiple of 5 and 7 both - 35
```

Comment: `if (i % 5 == 4 && i % 7 == 6) {` is shorter.

Comment: @Andreas how come it is shorter, i do not understand, pls explain. `i % 7 or i % 5` will be calculated always, just comparison will be with `0 or (4 or 6)`.

Comment: `i % 5 == 4` is shorter than `(i + 1) % 5 == 0` (10 chars vs 16 chars, and 2 ops vs 3 ops), and produce the same result. If you don't believe me, [check it out](https://ideone.com/LO6nNw).

Comment: @Andreas nothing like not believing you. :) i missed `(i + 1)` actually, even in my comment as well. answer edited as per your's

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [res]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [res] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

you can use the counters instead.

```
Object[] a = new Object[n];

        int counter = 2;
        int elementsCounter = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == elementsCounter )
            {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
                elementsCounter += counter;
                counter++;
            }
        }
```